# How to specify default json value in swagger php documentation?

Tags: php, json, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to specify a default json value in swagger docs for POST. I am getting T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS error. I have also tried escaping the ".

```
/**
     * @SWG\Api(path="/api/users",
     *   @SWG\Operation(
     *     method="POST",
     *     summary="Register a user",
     *     notes="Send a POST request along with required form parameters to add a new user",
     *     type="string",
     *     nickname="post-users",
     *     authorizations={},
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *       name="email",
     *       description="The email",
     *       required=true,
     *       type="json",
     *       paramType="body",
     *       allowMultiple=false,
     *       defaultValue = "{
  "email":"pradeep****@gmail.com",
  "first_name":"Pradeep",
  "last_name":"Kumar",
  "group":"subscriber",
  "password":"password"
}",
     *     ),
     *     
     *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=200,message="Success"),
     *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=400,message="Bad Request")
     *   )
     * )
     */
```

Comment: Sweet mother of god.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To escape a `"` in a doctrine/annotation use `""`

```
defaultValue="{""email"":""p****@gmail.com"",""first_name"":""Pradeep""}"
```

Comment: Perfect, just the answer I was looking for, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you should convert the `defaultValue` into a single line, and escape the quotes with a forward slash.

Comment: Fehguy, I have tried it and also mentioned in my question.

Comment: I have done this -

defaultValue = "{\"email\":\"pradeep****@gmail.com\",\"first_name\":\"Pradeep\",\"last_name\":\"Kumar\",\"group\":\"subscriber\",\"password\":\"password\"}"

Comment: Hi, I think you'll need to open an issue in the swagger-php repository:  https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php